# Does 'nick' mean 'idiot' in British English?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

I was watching 'On The Buses' (British comedy) and I came across the word 'nick' being used to mean something along the lines of 'idiot'. I've never heard *nick* being used to mean 'idiot'.

One of the character sat on a couch and there was a needle which pricked him. He said: *You stupid great nick*.

I searched in all the dictionaries I had access to but didn't find it used in this sense.

Does it mean 'idiot'?

[On The Buses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CjWs9gyJEk) - timestamp: 7:20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is "nit", which is indeed a word for "idiot" (but I don't think many people would use it now: slang goes in and out of fashion).

Comment: I’ve never heard “nit” but “nitwit” is common enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the meaning is idiot, fool. Actually a very old slang term:

***[Nit](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/dwpht6a)***

[SE nit, a louse; the implication is perhaps more of its insignificance than of its verminous qualities]

a fool.

> - c.1595  [UK]    Shakespeare Love’s Labour’s Lost IV i: Ah, heavens, it is a most pathetical nit.

(GDoS)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this misses a step - in this context 'nit' is short for 'nit-wit' i.e. someone with the mental faculties of a small insect typically found in human hair.